# MS SQL 5 column values same combination counts

Tags: sql-server, count, combinations

I am trying to count all possible same values from 5 columns with SQL.

For example, if there are matching values in 3 columns, it will return 3 in a `custom column` just like the below example:

```
A B C D E Count
1 1 1 1 1  5
1 1 N N N  2
```

Are there any ways to make these kinds of comparing with SQL?

Comment: Does `N` represent `NULL` or `'N'`?

Comment: This looks to be not optimal table design to me.  It would work better if you had just a _single_ column with the values, and a second column to keep track of the letter to which each value belongs.

Comment: N represent null and I agree this is bad table structure, but its going to be just one time use table

Answer (score 0):

***Assuming*** `N` represents `NULL` and not `'N'` you could Pivot the data out and then `COUNT` it:

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTable (A tinyint,
                         B tinyint,
                         C tinyint,
                         D tinyint,
                         E tinyint);
INSERT INTO #YourTable (A,
                        B,
                        C,
                        D,
                        E)
VALUES(1,1,1,1,1),
      (1,1,NULL,NULL,NULL);

GO

SELECT YT.A,
       YT.B,
       YT.C,
       YT.D,
       YT.E,
       (SELECT COUNT(V.Col)
        FROM (VALUES(YT.A),(YT.B),(YT.C),(YT.D),(YT.E))V(Col)) AS [Count]
FROM #YourTable YT;

GO
DROP TABLE #YourTable
```

But, like Tim said, I agree; you should really have normalised data, if this is something you actually need to do.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this would return wrong count if a,b,c,d have 1 and e has 2. I would like to return as 4 for this case. Thank you again!

Comment: Why do you want it to return 4, @ted? That isn't the logic in your question; you just have 1's and `NULL`; there is no mention of 2 or what do with it. What about the number 3, or -1 or the string `'missing'`. What else could there be..? Your comment and question don't align. The volunteers here can only ansee on the information you supply us.